# Can't configure jenkins with git

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab

I follow this guide https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/wiki/Setup-Example to entegrate Jenkins-Gitlab-Git.

I installed Jenkins,Git,Gitlab in same ubuntu server. And I create id_rsa.pub with Jenkins user. Then add into gitlab and jenkins.

When I tried

```
git ls-remote -h git@10.0.5.12:Intranet/Vardiya.git HEAD
```

There is no error on ubuntu command line.

On Jenkins project source config I can not pass that error.

[image]
[image]

Anyway I skip the error and create a webhook for Jenkins job on Gitlab. After Test ->  any event get this error.

[image]

Please Help !

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you input your *public key* in Jenkins's *private key* field

The private key should be in a file called `id_rsa`, not `id_rsa.pub`

Comment: Nice point thanks ! I passed first error. But still get _Hook executed ..._ the last one

Comment: I don't know about that, sorry